# Slightly wet bolts

Tags: bolts

I was replacing my brake pads and rotors yesterday. While I was in the middle of the job it started to snow. I finished the job while it was still snowing.

Later, when it was time to put together everything back on the vehicle, I realised that the bolts that hold the brake caliper and the lug nuts got snow on them and got wet. I wiped them the best I could and screwed them back on.

I am worried that I might have not done a good enough job with wiping them and I am worried that the bolts might begin to rust and create issues if I need to remove them ever. Is there anything that I can do about it now?
I am not sure if I am overthinking this issue.

To summarize, I screwed back the brake caliper bolts and lugs while they were slightly wet. Is that a major issue?

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you can do about them getting wet. It's a fact of life these will get wet during normal usage (as jwh20 points out in their answer). What you could do is take the bolts back off and coat them with anti-seize. This would (for the most part) protect them from corroding and make it easier for the next time you need to do the brake job.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to keep those bolts from becoming wet during normal driving in wet conditions.  Yes they fit tightly but they are not water-tight.

I don't see how any problem is going to come as a result of this.